# What is the most efficient way to read ERC20 balances without knowing the tokens that the address might hold?

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20, balances, explorers

There are plenty of examples of reading the balance of an ERC20 token from an address via a `balanceOf.call` when knowing the token contract address beforehand. However, how would one go about reading the balance of an address without knowing which tokens the address might hold?

For example, a user wishes to know the total balance (ETH + tokens) of his address. What would be the most efficient way of retrieving this information without doing any unnecessary calculations?

Should I just loop through an array of the most popular token contract addresses? Look at the incoming token transfer events? or are there more efficient ways?

*Just to specify, I am looking for a solution with a private node not an API.*

Examples of pages that have achieved this:

- https://etherscan.io/
- https://ethplorer.io/
- https://qwallet.io/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested in just a relatively small subset of popular ERC20 tokens, then looping over them might be okay.

But if you want everything, I think your best bet is to process the logs as you go and look for `Transfer(address,address,uint256)` events. For each event, if the source looks like an ERC20 token (e.g. has name/symbol/decimals), do some accounting in your database where you're keeping track of these things.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just to clarify, what would you say would constitute as a “relatively small subset”? Would you see it being less than 50, 100 or a 1000 tokens? 

In terms of the log processing, if I understand correctly, this would require keeping track of all the token transfers events occurring at every new block as well as all the transfers that have occurred since block 0 for every Ethereum address currently in use? Or is it somehow possible to access the transfer event logs per account?

Comment: I was thinking of watching all the `Transfer` events since block 0. But you probably want to check `balanceOf(<address>)` for the definitive answer rather than sum up the `Transfer`s, because some token contracts may, e.g., pay interest or deduct transfer fees or other things like that. So i'd use `Transfer` events to identify the ERC20 contracts, and then I'd call `balanceOf(<address>)` for each address I saw appear in those `Transfer` events.

Comment: In terms of what subset is "small," I'd recommend testing `balanceOf` calls for tokens to see how quickly you can do them. Presumably you're thinking about doing this on the fly when a user wants to see balances, so it's really a performance question of what seems fast enough.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I’ll try and run some test later and post back with the results.

Comment: Also, for anyone wondering how to get the `Transfer` event logs since block 0 I found this related post https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/26621/28839

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @smarx, I went ahead and tested the efficiency of simply looping over a subset of ERC20 contracts with a `balanceOf` method and here are the results:

*Median response time for number of token contracts using the **Infura RPC** (this includes getting the token symbol, balance and decimals)*

- 1 = 0.6s
- **10 = 0.8s**
- 50 = 1.2s
- 100 = 1.5s
- 200 = 2s
- 300 = 2.5s
- **400 = 3s**
- 500 = 3.5s
- 1000 = 6s

**Judging by the fact that there are a total of 410 Ethereum tokens listed on *Coinmarketcap*, simply looping through 400 token contracts would take about 3s, which might be adequate depending on the use case.**

Knowing the tokens which the address holds, would thereby increase the efficiency by about 2.3s (assuming that an average address hold about 5 tokens). This would certainly lead to a better UX, but would also entail extra maintenance overhead in observing the `Transfer` events.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote about this issue here: https://medium.com/@tjayrush/how-many-tokens-do-you-have-eae7233676f1. Summary it’s as difficult as you think it might be.

If you really want every token that your address holds, you have to spin through every transaction.